# Excel macro to make selected range absolute or relative reference?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I stumbled across a macro some time ago that would allow you to make your selected cells absolute or relative references (would prompt you to choose 1 of 4 options) then make the update accordingly. You didn't need to adjust the code to input workbook/sheet names as it worked off the currently active/selected cells. I have been searching for it again and could not find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this from [Scott](https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-convert-absolute-reference-to-relative-reference.html)?

You select the range/area and it give you the ability to change it.

Then you can choose between Absolute, Row Absolute, Column Absolute or Relative Reference.

```
Sub ConverReferenceType()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myRange = Application.Selection
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select one Range that you want to covert reference type:", "ConvertReferenceType", myRange.Address, Type:=8)
    Set myRange = myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
     myIndex = Application.InputBox("Select a reference type from below list:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
    & "Absolute = 1" & Chr(13) _
    & "Row absolute = 2" & Chr(13) _
    & "Column absolute = 3" & Chr(13) _
    & "Relative = 4", "ConvertReferenceType", 1, Type:=1)
    For Each R In myRange
       R.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(R.Formula, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, myIndex)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If you don't want the reference box to appear you can comment out this line

```
'Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select one Range that you want to covert reference type:", "ConvertReferenceType", myRange.Address, Type:=8)
```